# Get a queryset from another Model in a queryset in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, drf-queryset

```
class V(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    doc = models.ForeignKey(D, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('upload_time',)

 class D(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

in a ModelViewSet I wrote like this:

```
class index(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = VSerializer
    queryset = V.objects.all()
```

I have obtained those data through the API

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "title": xxxxx
 "d_id": 8,
  ...
  ...
}
```

However, I wanna the d_id to be more specific, like this:

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "title": xxxxx
 "d_id": {
     "id": 8,
     "name": xxx,
     ....
   }
...
...
}
```

So the data in the D Model has been fetched through the d_id=8 and attached into the original queryset.

How could I do this? Need your help...

Comment: You should have posted the models. But did you read the extremely comprehensive DRF docs on [serializer relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)? What there failed to answer your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have checked the doc that you mentioned. As your point, the "Nested relationships" looks like my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a serializer for your model D.

```
class DSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = D
        fields = ('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3')
```

And in your VSerializer add a serializer field like this:

```
class VSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    d = DSerializer() # This will add D's fields in V's API.
    class Meta:
        model = V
        fields = ('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3')
```

Read this documentation for more details.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got another similar issue, but unlike this one the D's primary key is not one of the field of V. Could u pls help me figure it out if you got time? thx again! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141769/upload-multiple-images-in-django-admin