# Upload multiple images in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

`models.py`

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    details = models.TextField()

class VideoDetails(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='videos')
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/video/%Y/%m/%d')
```

`serializers.py`

```
class VideoDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VideoDetails
        fields = '__all__'

class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = '__all__'
```

`admin.py`

```
class VideoDetailsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = VideoDetails

class VideoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [VideoDetailsInline]

admin.site.register(Video, VideoAdmin)
```

[image]
[image]

As shown above, I uploaded 3 images for video 2. However, in my `VideoList` view, I didn't get the urls of those images.

`views.py`

```
class VideoList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
```

How can I attach those image url in `VideoDetail` to the `queryset` of `Video`? Need your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your files according to that and don't forget configure a *[MEDIA_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#media-url)*

`models.py`

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

class VideoDetails(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='videos')
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/video/%Y/%m/%d')

    def get_absolute_image_url(self):
        return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.images.url)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class VideoDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    image_url = serializers.URLField(source='get_absolute_image_url', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = VideoDetails
        fields = ('video', 'image_url')


class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    video_details = VideoDetailsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ('title', 'details', 'video_details')
```

Comment: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `video_details` on serializer `VideoSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Video` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Video' object has no attribute 'video_details'. Anything goes wrong?

Comment: @mrhaoji Change line in `VideoSerializer` according to that
 `video_details = VideoDetailsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`